# Print Image pixel values for coordinates from asset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I managed to get value for single pixel with this code, but I would like to get this value for every coordinates from this asset - https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/jakubhrouda/nandu. I have tried several codes for creating tables with results for coordinates in FeatureCollections, but none of them worked for me.

What should I add to this code to match data from FeatureCollection and values from Image?

```
// The pixel's coordinate       
var lng = -91.5;
var lat = 30.0919;
var r = ee.Geometry.Point(lng, lat); // r is the pixel of interest

// Load copernicus image
var collection = ee.Image('COPERNICUS/Landcover/100m/Proba-V-C3/Global/2019');

  
// print pixel value of image in the console
var pixelInfo = collection.reduceRegion({
  geometry: r,
  scale: 30, // nominal sclae landsat
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
});
print(pixelInfo.get('discrete_classification'))

//show image and pixes
Map.addLayer(collection, {}, 'map');
Map.addLayer(r, {}, 'pixel');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Image.reduceRegions`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image-reduceregions). It is very similar to `reduceRegion`, but it takes a `FeatureCollection` instead of a `Geometry`, and the output will be a `FeatureCollection` like the input. For each feature, the reducer will be run over the portion of the image covered by the feature's geometry (like `reduceRegion`), and the reducer's outputs will be added as properties to the features (instead of being returned as a dictionary).